# When adding tags to a Question, the Excerpt for [seo-friendly] does not match that of its master

Tags: bug, user-interface, tag-synonyms, tag-autocomplete

As an example, if you try [py3k](/questions/tagged/py3k), only [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) is shown. But if you try [seo-friendly](/questions/tagged/seo-friendly), it shows up, complete with its own Excerpt, even if it's just a synonym (of [seo](/questions/tagged/seo)). I don't know what was intended, so I don't know which is the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because there are still 310 questions that actually have the tag [seo-friendly](/questions/tagged/seo-friendly) on them. So when looking for that tag, it will appear in two places: under its master tag as a synonym and as its own tag because it has questions.

[image: seo-friendly tag]

The [py3k](/questions/tagged/py3k) tag has no questions under it; it's *only* a synonym. So it doesn't show up separately.

[image: py3k tag suggestion]

---

Once all the questions with the [seo-friendly](/questions/tagged/seo-friendly) tag have been retagged, it will no longer appear as a separate tag in the tag suggestions popup. I've gone ahead and just merged it into its master tag, so it should stop doing that shortly.

Comment: I thought this merging happens automatically when a master-synonym relationship is created.

Comment: @Tshepang No. Only moderators can merge two tags.

Comment: How would one access Questions tagged only with [tag:seo-friendly] without getting redirected to [tag:seo]? I guess it's not possible?

Comment: You could search for something like `[seo] -[seo]`, which would return anything that gets remapped to the SEO tag but doesn't *actually* have the SEO tag on it. But that would also exclude any questions tagged with *both*.

Comment: I suggest using the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/142281)